Why doesn't net work equation take the change in potential energy into account?
I know that
$$\text{net work} = \text{work done by conservative forces} + \text{work done by non-conservative forces}.$$
and
$$\begin{split}\text{net work} & = \text{change in kinetic energy} + \text{change in potential energy} - \text{change in potential energy} \\& = \text{change in kinetic energy}\end{split}.$$
I also know that elastic potential energy is $k x^2/2$.
Therefore, my question is that for example if you compress a spring by $x$, then aren't you doing work on the spring? Therefore, how do we incorporate it as part of the work-energy equation?

Where does the "-change in potential energy" term come from in your equation?

The 'change in potential energy' term comes from the equation of net work.
Net work = work done by conservative forces + work done by non-conservative forces
Work done by conservative forces = - (change in potential energy)
Work done by non-conservative forces = change in potential energy + change in kinetic energy.
Substituting the above we get:
net work = change in kinetic energy + change in potential energy + (-change in potential energy) = change in kinetic energy

I think you are misunderstanding some things. 1. Action of conservative forces can change kinetic energy --- just think of an electron being accelerated between the electrodes of a vacuum tube. 2. We can't define potentials for non-conservative forces so it doesn't always make sense to talk about the change in potential energy due to the action of a non-conservative force. Often the action of a non-conservative force results in energy converting to some other form such as heat and being "lost" from the system (for example, in the case of mechanical friction).
